# APC Fragmentation

Tags: apc, fragmentation

I have APC with my Wordpress website

See my APC summary page here

http://www.animefushigi.com/apc.php

I notice I have a very high amount of fragments (over 10,000)

Is this a bad thing? Will it decrease performance?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps your cache entries expire too quickly and thus create the fragmentation.

Your current stats show: "Fragmentation: 0.33% ( 1.2 MBytes out of 349.3 MBytes in 4594 fragments) " so it seems there's no reason to worry about anything.

You might wanna change apc.stat=0 to increase performance but read about it carefully in the documentation before making the change http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php